# Initializer_list as args to a variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I am trying to have a initializer_list as an argument for a variadic template. But I get the error message: `could not deduce template argument for 'Types' from 'initializer-list'`
Is there somehow I can achieve this?

```
struct Struct {
  int a, b;
};

 template<typename Type, typename ...Types>
 void func(vector<Type>, initializer_list<Struct> lists, Types... args) {
 }

int main() {
  vector<float> vec;

  func(vec, { Struct{ 1, 2 } });
  func(vec, { Struct{ 1, 2 } }, vec, { Struct{ 2, 2 } });
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `{..}` is a braced-init-list, which is not an expression and does not have a type. You have to (manually) specify the type.

Comment: Why not `func(vec, Struct{ 1, 2 }, vec, Struct{ 2, 2 });`?

Comment: Do you want to convert `{ Struct{1,2} }` to a `vector<Struct>` implicitly?

Comment: Yes, I guess this will work, but its not as good looking.
func(vec, vector<Struct>{ Struct{ 1, 2 } }, vec, vector<Struct>{ Struct{ 1, 2 } });

Comment: What you describe above cannot be done.  Can you explain what your actual problem was that led you to try to do what you did above?

Comment: @dyp Why doesn't this special case for function template argument deduction apply? Quoting from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) : "If removing references and cv-qualifiers from P gives std::initializer_list
and A is a braced-init-list, then deduction is performed for every element of the initializer list, taking P' as the parameter and the list element as the argument."

Comment: @dyp Sorry, I thought the error in deduction was in the first `func` call. Completely missed the second one.

Comment: @Pradhan OP has also changed the code in the question. But indeed, the problem still remains for the parameter pack.